# Microsoft Excel: How to convert grading percentage to a numeric marking rubric?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet setup for marking rubric purposes.  I have converted all of the grades into a percentage (1-100 numeric) value.

I'm having trouble creating a function that converts that percentage into a marking rubric I've made.

Ideally, I would want a new cell to reference the percentage then assign a 0-4 value

80%-100% = 4

60%-80% = 3

40%-60% = 2

20%-40% = 1

0%-20% = 0

Here's an example of my sheet

[image]

I'm hoping to have the resulting rubric grade in cells L2-L7.

I've read that "LOOKUP" or "VLOOKUP" can do this but I can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: Unclear............... should ***80%*** map to *3* or to *4* ??

Comment: And the number you want to check is in K2?  If so is that number `100` or `1` formatted differently?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are every 20% you can do simple math:

```
=MIN(INT(K2/20),4)
```

This assumes the values in K2 is `100` and not `1`

If `1` then change to:

```
 =MIN(INT(K2/.2),4)
```

But if you want VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(K2,{0,0;20,1;40,2;60,3;80,4},2,TRUE)
```

Or

```
=INDEX({0,1,2,3,4},MATCH(K2,{0,20,40,60,80},1))
```

Again this assumes your numbers are `100` not `1`.  If the other replace all the `20,40,60,80` with `.2,.4,.6,.8`

Answer (score 1):

With a percentage in **A1**, in **B1**:

```
=ROUNDUP(A1*5-1,0)
```